# Showing Isomorphism between Semi direct product $C_7 \rtimes C_3$ and presentation G

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, semidirect-product

I was given the following two problems. Is my solution correct?

(1) Let G = $\langle a,b | a^7 = b^3 = 1, bab^{-1} = a^2\rangle$
Show this is isomorphic to $H = C_7 \rtimes C_3$ for some $\phi: C_3 \rightarrow Aut(C_7)$. Give explicitly what $\phi$ is.
Here $C_i$ represents the cyclic group of order i.

By the universal property we have a homomorphism $f: G \rightarrow H$ provided that we can map the generators in G to elements in H such that the relations are satisfied.

Clearly, we map $a \rightarrow (1,0)$ and $b \rightarrow (0,1)$ which satisfies the relations $a^7 = b^3 = 1$ since the identity is $(0,0)$ for H.

Now, the last relation allows us to determine $\phi$ explicitly as follows:

To calculate $a^2$ in H we have:

$(1,0)(1,0) = (1+1,0) = (2,0)$

To calculate $bab^{-1}$ we have:

$(0,1)(1,0)(0,1)^{-1} = (0 + \phi(1)(1), 1+0)(0, 2) = (\phi(1)(1), 1)(0, 2) = (\phi(1)(1) + \phi(1)(0), 1+2) = (\phi(1)(1), 0)$

where we have used the fact that $\phi(1)(0) = 0$ and $(0,1)^{-1} = (0,2)$.

Thus, we must have $\phi(1)(1) = 2$. But this completely determines $\phi$ since $C_3$ and $C_7$ are both cyclic. So we have a homomorphism f between G and H, as desired.

Now, to show it's an isomorphism, we would need to show f is injective since it's clearly onto (since f maps to the generators). But how do I show this part?

(2) For G = $\langle a,b | a^7 = b^3 = 1, bab^{-1} = a^3\rangle$, determine what group it is isomorphic to.

The hint given was to simplify the relations.
I did this as follows:

$bab^{-1} = a^3 \implies ba^3b^{-1} = a^2 \implies b^2ab^{-2} = a^2 \implies b^2a^3b^{-2} = a^6 \implies b^3ab^{-3} = a^6 \implies a = a^6 \implies a^2 = 1$ we cubed both sides, subbed in, cubed again, etc.

But $a^7 = a^2 = 1 \implies a = 1$. Thus, the presentation reduces to one generator b with the relation $b^3 = 1$. Thus it must be the case that $G \simeq C_3$.

Could it also be the case that G is the trivial group as well? Or do we just exclude this possibility?

Comment: I think for part (2) you need to show that there exists a group of order $3$ satisfying the relations; it's so obvious that we usually forget to prove it, and only careful people like yourself notice it's a problem.

Comment: In part (1) I think that what you have proved is that if there is an automorphism $\phi$, then we must have $\phi(1)(1)=2$ and then if it's an automorphism we'll know all $\phi(m)(n)$. But I don't think you've proved that this map $\phi$ actually is an automorphism. (I don't think  it's difficult, I just think you haven't yet proved it.)

Comment: @ancientmathematician For (2) the group $C_3$ we can map 1 to b and clearly $1^3 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 0$ in $C_3$ so that relation holds. I guess I'm just wondering if it's correct to say another possibility is that G is simply the trivial subgroup since mapping the identity element to b we get $e^3 = e$ so it too satisfies the relation. As for part (1), I think that is easy to show as well since $\phi(1)(x+y) = 2(x+y) = 2x + 2y = \phi(1)(x) + \phi(1)(y)$ and it's injective since $\phi(1)(x) = \phi(1)(y)$ iff $2x = 2y$ iff $x=y$ and since they are finite, $\phi(1)$ is indeed an automorphism.

Comment: The presentation in (2) defines the cyclic group of order 3 and not the identity group.      Although (as you say) we can assign $a, b$ to $e$ and see that the relations are satisfied, it is not the case that $b=1$ is a consequence of the three relations in the presentation. You're right about (1), I just think you need to say it in the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps all of what I am going to say is already obvious to you, still.

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$Consider the first group. You have proved that there is a *surjective* homomorphism $f : G \to H$. So you know that $G$ has order *at least* $21$ (at this stage, it could conceivably be infinite).

Now if we prove that $G$ has order *at most* $21$, we're done, because $f$ will turn out to be a surjective map between two finite sets with the same number of elements, and thus $f$ is bijective.

To show this, consider the subset
$$
S = \Set{ a^{j} b^{i} : 0 \le i < 3, 0 \le j < 7 }
$$
of $G$. This has order *at most* $21$. We will show that this is a subgroup of $G$. Since it contains the generators $a, b$ of $G$, we have $S = G$, and you're done.

Let $a^{j} b^{i} , a^{n} b^{m}  \in S$, and consider the product
$$
a^{j} b^{i} \cdot a^{n} b^{m} 
=
a^{j + 2^{i} n} b^{i+m},
$$
where we have repeatedly used the fact that
$$
b a^{x}
=
b a^{x} b^{-1} b
=
(b a b^{-1})^{x} b
=
a^{2 x} b.
$$
Using the relations $a^{7} = 1$ and $b^{3} = 1$, we see that the product lies in $S$. A similar argument applies to the inverse; or you can reduce the calculation of the inverse to that of the product: consider $a^{j} b^{i} \in S$, then
$$
(a^{j} b^{i})^{-1} = b^{-i} a^{-j} = b^{m} a^{n} = (a^{0} b^{m}) \cdot (a^{n} b^{0}) \in S,
$$
where $0 \le m < 3, 0 \le n < 7$ are obtained from the relations $a^{7} = 1$ and $b^{3} = 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes sense. A quick question in terms of making this part of the proof even shorter. Could we simply say the following: since $ba = a^3b$ for any element in G we can move all the b's to the right and all the a's to the left so that every element in G can be written as $a^ib^j$. Then clearly from the first two relations, i is between 0 and 6, j is between 0 and 2, leaving at most $7(3) = 21$ elements in G. Is that sound reasoning?

Comment: Absolutely, that's how I would see it. In writing it down, I have preferred to be more detailed.